# Show that $\displaystyle (1-|z|)|f'(z)|\leq\sup_{z\in D}|f(z)|$ for all $z\in D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a bounded analytic function on the open unit disk $D$. Show that $$ (1-|z|)|f'(z)|\leq\sup_{z\in D}|f(z)|$$ for all $z\in D$

Fix $z_{0}\in\mathbb{D}$. Let $r=1-|z_{0}|\in(0,1]$ if $|u-z_{0}|<r
$, then $|u|\leq|u-z_{0}|+|z_{0}|<r+|z_{0}|=1$. And hence $D_{z_{0}}(r)\subseteq\mathbb{D}$. Can anyone help me proceed further?

Comment: @MarkViola  I believe that the problem is correct as stated by the OP, but I don't know how to prove.

Comment: @MarkViola I checked the problem again, it is not wrong.

Comment: @MarkViola  I merely checked with many analytic functions and the inequality seems to check out.

Comment: @Zvi I've got it now and have edited my solution accordingly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Cauchy's Integral Formula, we have for $|z|< 1$

$$f'(z)=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z')}{(z'-z)^2}\,dz'\tag 1$$

Then we have the following estimates

$$\begin{align}
|f'(z)|&=\left|\frac1{i2\pi}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z')}{(z-z')^2}\,dz'\right|\\\\
&\le \frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{|f(e^{i\phi})|}{|z-e^{i\phi}|^2}\,d\phi\\\\
&\le \sup_{z\in \partial \mathbb{D}}|f(z)|\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{|z|^2+1-2|z|\cos(\phi-\arg(z))}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\sup_{z\in \partial \mathbb{D}}|f(z)|\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{|z|^2+1-2|z|\cos(\phi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\sup_{z\in \partial \mathbb{D}}|f(z)|\times \frac{1}{1-|z|^2}\\\\
&\le \sup_{z\in \partial \mathbb{D}}|f(z)|\times \frac{1}{1-|z|}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Rearranging $(2)$ yields

$$(1-|z|)|f'(z)|\le \sup_{z\in  \partial \mathbb{D}}|f(z)| $$

Since

Since the supremum of $|f(z)|$ on $\mathbb{D}$ is equal to the supremum of $|f(z)|$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$, we have

$$(1-|z|)|f'(z)|\le \sup_{z\in  \mathbb{D}}|f(z)| $$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Can you explain what $z'$ is here? I understand everything you wrote, but trying to understand the Cauchy Integral Formula you have there.

Comment: And also, when you parametrised the $z'$ to $z'(\phi)$, would you not have to multiply it by $ie^{i\phi}$?

Comment: First, $z'$ is a "dummy" variable.  Second, $(1)$ is a consequence of differentiating  Cauchy's Integral Formula.   And with $z'=e^{i\phi}$, $|e^{i\phi}|=1$.

Comment: @YaG I've found a better estimate and it leads to the coveted result!

Comment: @MarkViola  Wonderful!  Thanks for letting me know.  I cannot vote up for the second time, unfortunately.

Comment: From your proof, I think the inequality $$\big(1-|z|^2\big)\big|f'(z)\big|\leq \sup_{z\in D}f(z)$$ is always strict unless $f$ is identically zero.